# L-layer Neural Network in python

Tags: python

I have tried Coursera Lab where I got this type of error and I have tried many method to solve

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: L_layer_model

def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):#lr was 0.009
    """
    Implements a L-layer neural network: [LINEAR->RELU]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SIGMOID.
    
    Arguments:
    X -- data, numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if cat, 1 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
    layers_dims -- list containing the input size and each layer size, of length (number of layers + 1).
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
    num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
    print_cost -- if True, it prints the cost every 100 steps
    
    Returns:
    parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
    """

    np.random.seed(1)
    costs = []                         # keep track of cost
    
    # Parameters initialization. (≈ 1 line of code)
    ### START CODE HERE ###
    parameters = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Loop (gradient descent)
    for i in range(0, num_iterations):

        # Forward propagation: [LINEAR -> RELU]*(L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID.
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
        AL, caches = L_model_forward(X, parameters)
        ### END CODE HERE ###
        
        # Compute cost.
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
        cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)
        ### END CODE HERE ###
    
        # Backward propagation.
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
        grads = L_model_backward(AL, Y, caches)
        ### END CODE HERE ###
 
        # Update parameters.
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
        parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
        ### END CODE HERE ###
                
        # Print the cost every 100 training example
        if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
            print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))
        if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)
            
    # plot the cost
    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('iterations (per hundreds)')
    plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
    plt.show()
    
    return parameters
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-d5e7eb27c0fc> in <module>
----> 1 parameters, costs = L_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims, num_iterations = 1, print_cost = False)
      2 
      3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
      4 
      5 L_layer_model_test(L_layer_model)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## GRADED FUNCTION: L_layer_model

def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):#lr was 0.009
"""
Implements a L-layer neural network: [LINEAR->RELU]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SIGMOID.

```
Arguments:
X -- data, numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if cat, 1 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
layers_dims -- list containing the input size and each layer size, of length (number of layers + 1).
learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
print_cost -- if True, it prints the cost every 100 steps

Returns:
parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
"""

np.random.seed(1)
costs = []                         # keep track of cost

# Parameters initialization. (≈ 1 line of code)
### START CODE HERE ###
parameters = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Loop (gradient descent)
for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation: [LINEAR -> RELU]*(L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    AL, caches = L_model_forward(X,parameters)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Compute cost.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Backward propagation.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    grads = L_model_backward(AL, Y, caches)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Update parameters.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
            
    # Print the cost every 100 training example
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0 or i== num_iterations - 1:
        print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, np.squeeze(cost)))
    if i % 100 == 0 or i == num_iterations:
        costs.append(cost)

return parameters, costs
```

Answer (score -2):

The error message `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` indicates that your function is not providing the predicted number of values. Within your code, you are endeavoring to assign the output of the `L_layer_model` function to two variables: `parameters` and `costs`. Nevertheless, your function is currently only set up to give one value: `parameters`.

To rectify this, you need to alter the function to yield both `parameters` and `costs`. Here's how you could adapt your function:

```py
def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):#lr was 0.009
    """
    Implements a L-layer neural network: [LINEAR->RELU]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SIGMOID.
    
    Arguments:
    X -- data, numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if cat, 1 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
    layers_dims -- list containing the input size and each layer size, of length (number of layers + 1).
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
    num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
    print_cost -- if True, it prints the cost every 100 steps
    
    Returns:
    parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
    costs -- list of costs at every 100 steps of training
    """

    # ... existing code ...

    # plot the cost
    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('iterations (per hundreds)')
    plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
    plt.show()
    
    return parameters, costs  # changed this line to return costs as well
```

After this modification, you should be able to call your function like this without getting a ValueError:

```py
parameters, costs = L_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims, num_iterations = 1, print_cost = False)
```